How to Update Payment Method Entities with Confirmed Invoice Details in Spring Boot?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I need to update the payment method entities (e.g., CardEntity,CashEntity) with the confirmed invoice details once an invoice is confirmed. Here’s a simplified version of my current setup:
CardEntity.java:
@Entity
@Table(name = "card_tbl")
public class CardEntity {
    @Id
    private Long cardRefNo;

    private Double paidAmount;
    private Date paidDate;

    private Long paymentId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tempInvoiceId")
    private TempInvoiceEntity tempInvoiceEntity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "confirmInvoiceId")
    private ConfirmInvoiceEntity confirmInvoiceEntity;

    // Getters and Setters
}


ConfirmInvoiceServiceImple.java:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConfirmInvoiceServiceImple implements ConfirmInvoiceService {

    private final TempInvoiceRepo tempInvoiceRepo;
    private final ConfirmInvoiceRepo confirmInvoiceRepo;
    private final ConfirmProductCartService confirmProductCartService;
    private final PaymentsRepo paymentsRepo;
    private final CardRepo cardRepo;
    private final CashRepo cashRepo;
    private final ChequeRepo chequeRepo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public NonPaginatedResponse insertIntoConfirmInvoice(Long invoiceId) {
        NonPaginatedResponse response = new NonPaginatedResponse();
        try {
            TempInvoiceEntity selectedTempInvoice = tempInvoiceRepo.findById(invoiceId).get();
            ConfirmInvoiceEntity confirmedInvoice = createNewConfirmInvoiceData(selectedTempInvoice);
            Boolean isCartItemsConfirmed = confirmProductCartService.confirmTheCartItems(invoiceId, confirmedInvoice);
            if (isCartItemsConfirmed) {
                List<PaymentsEntity> selectAllPayments = paymentsRepo.findBySalesInvoice_TempInvoiceId(confirmedInvoice.getConfirmInvoiceId());
                List<PaymentsEntity> listOfPayments = selectAllPayments.stream().map(
                        payment -> {
                            PaymentsEntity aPay = new PaymentsEntity();
                            aPay.setPaymentType(payment.getPaymentType());
                            aPay.setPaidDate(payment.getPaidDate());
                            aPay.setPaidAmount(payment.getPaidAmount());
                            aPay.setConfirmInvoice(confirmedInvoice);
                            aPay.setSalesInvoice(null);
                            alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice(payment, confirmedInvoice);
                            return aPay;
                        }
                ).toList();
                paymentsRepo.saveAll(listOfPayments);
                tempInvoiceRepo.deleteById(confirmedInvoice.getConfirmInvoiceId());
            }
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
            response.setSuccessMessage("Invoice has been confirmed.");
            response.setResult(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setErrors(Collections.singletonList("Couldn't confirm the selected invoice"));
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
        }
        return response;
    }

    public void alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice(PaymentsEntity payment, ConfirmInvoiceEntity confirmedInvoice) {
        if (payment.getPaymentType().equalsIgnoreCase("card")) {
            List<CardEntity> cardEntities = cardRepo.findByTempInvoiceEntity_TempInvoiceId(payment.getPaymentId());
            for (CardEntity cardEntity : cardEntities) {
                cardEntity.setConfirmInvoiceEntity(confirmedInvoice);
            }
            cardRepo.saveAll(cardEntities);
        }
    }

    private ConfirmInvoiceEntity createNewConfirmInvoiceData(TempInvoiceEntity tempInvoiceEntity) {
        ConfirmInvoiceEntity confirmInvoiceEntity = new ConfirmInvoiceEntity();
        confirmInvoiceEntity.setConfirmInvoiceId(tempInvoiceEntity.getTempInvoiceId());
        confirmInvoiceEntity.setInvoiceNumber(tempInvoiceEntity.getTempInvoiceNumber());
        confirmInvoiceEntity.setDate(new Date());
        confirmInvoiceEntity.setPaidAmount(tempInvoiceEntity.getPaidAmount());
        confirmInvoiceEntity.setNetAmount(tempInvoiceEntity.getNetAmount());
        confirmInvoiceEntity.setCustomer(tempInvoiceEntity.getCustomer());
        return confirmInvoiceRepo.save(confirmInvoiceEntity);
    }
}


CardRepo.java:
@Repository
public interface CardRepo extends JpaRepository<CardEntity, Long> {
    List<CardEntity> findByTempInvoiceEntity_TempInvoiceId(Long tempInvoiceId);
}


In the alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice method, I retrieve the CardEntity instances associated with a specific TempInvoiceId and update them with the ConfirmInvoiceEntity details.
Although the payment entity is being set with the confirmInvoice details perfectly when the invoice is confirmed, the confirmInvoice isn't getting set inside the alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice function. What could be causing this issue?
I even tried to pass all the Updated payments as a List and then tried getting the "card" details and updated the confirmedInvoice with in alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice(), but isn't helping at all.
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public NonPaginatedResponse insertIntoConfirmInvoice(Long invoiceId) {
        NonPaginatedResponse response = new NonPaginatedResponse();
        try {
            TempInvoiceEntity selectedTempInvoice = tempInvoiceRepo.findById(invoiceId).get();

            ConfirmInvoiceEntity confirmedInvoice = createNewConfirmInvoiceData(selectedTempInvoice);
            Boolean isCartItemsConfirmed = confirmProductCartService.confirmTheCartItems(invoiceId, confirmedInvoice);
            if (isCartItemsConfirmed) {
                List<PaymentsEntity> selectAllPayments = paymentsRepo.findBySalesInvoice_TempInvoiceId(confirmedInvoice.getConfirmInvoiceId());
                alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice(selectAllPayments, confirmedInvoice);
                List<PaymentsEntity> listOfPayments = selectAllPayments.stream().map(
                        payment -> {
                            PaymentsEntity aPay = new PaymentsEntity();
                            aPay.setPaymentType(payment.getPaymentType());
                            aPay.setPaidDate(payment.getPaidDate());
                            aPay.setPaidAmount(payment.getPaidAmount());
                            aPay.setConfirmInvoice(confirmedInvoice);
                            aPay.setSalesInvoice(null);

                            return aPay;
                        }
                ).toList();
                paymentsRepo.saveAll(listOfPayments);
                tempInvoiceRepo.deleteById(confirmedInvoice.getConfirmInvoiceId());
            }
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
            response.setSuccessMessage(ConfirmInvoiceConsonants.INVOICE_HAS_BEEN_CONFIRMED);
            response.setResult(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setErrors(Arrays.asList("Couldn't Confirm the selected invoice"));
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
        }
        return response;
    }


    public void alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice(List<PaymentsEntity> selectAllPayments, ConfirmInvoiceEntity confirmedInvoice) {
        selectAllPayments.stream().filter(
                allPay->{
                    if (allPay.getPaymentType().equalsIgnoreCase("card")) {
                        List<CardEntity> cardEntities = cardRepo.findByTempInvoiceEntity_TempInvoiceId(confirmedInvoice.getConfirmInvoiceId());
                        for (CardEntity cardEntity : cardEntities) {
                            cardEntity.setConfirmInvoiceEntity(confirmedInvoice);
                        }
                        cardRepo.saveAll(cardEntities);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
        ).toList();


    }



Your alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice method looks very dubious. Why do you do so much in the filter method and also why do you collect the result in a list, which you don't use after that?

Don't you see the problem of doing repeated repository hits?

Ensure that the method alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoice is executed within a transaction (add the @Transactional annotation to the method). If not, changes made to the entities might not be persisted in the database.

alterPaymentMethConfirmInvoiceis being called from within insertIntoConfirmInvoicewhich is @Transactional. This is not the solution.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
